# Trying to learn TDD - not going so well

Tags: python, tdd

I've been trying to learn Python for about 6 weeks now. After reading a lot about TDD on this site I bought *The Art of Unit Testing* by Roy Osherove (great book!) to try and experiment with TDD while also learning Python. The book uses .NET but it doesn't seem to be a problem. Stubs are stubs, and mocks are mocks.

While I'm reading, and seeing TDD examples online, I really feel like I understand why the coder wrote the code as they did. But as soon as I sit down and try myself, I get nowhere.

Let me give you an example from yesterday:

I wanted to try TDD for a not-so-complicated project. Basically, what I want is a class that, by downloading and parsing an RSS feed, holds a list of tuples containing (name, date). I created a new py-file for my tests (no "real code" written yet) and wrote a test case:

```
import unittest

from tv_schedule import TvSchedule

class TvScheduleTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_download_success_and_parse_failure(self):
        '''Successfully download RSS schedule for the specific user
           but fail parsing it'''
        self.tv = TvSchedule("User123")
        # Check if ParserException was thrown I guess


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

...and then I'm kind of stuck. I think (lol!). I really need some pointers on if this is just stupid and/or how I could do this better. My intuition says that I've done something bad.

I'd like to let the TvSchedule class do the downloading/parsing in the background (using [feedparser](http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries)) so you just create a new instance of the class and then just use it. Maybe this is bad design and also making it hard to test? Also, how would I remove the dependency on retrieving the rss feed over the network? By stubbing it and always return an in-memory string containing a sample feed?

As soon as I leave the really simple calculator examples that TDD tutorials and books love to use, I get stuck. :(

Comment: I think learning Python *and* TDD at the same time might be a bad idea. TDD is tricky enough to get the hang of without adding a new language to the mix :)

Comment: Note that "pure" TDD only works well where you have a good idea of where you are going with the code. You might like to start writing enough code to firm up your ideas, then write a test for it (which should shake out any issues you haven't addressed), then fix up your code.

Comment: @kigurai: That may be. I figured I'd try though. Some people seem to think that it is easier to get into the TDD mindset while lacking the traditional one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One challenge you may be running into is that your test is simply too broad. Downloading and parsing all at once means you'll be writing a lot of code. Try squeezing the first test down a bit. That may help give you some focus.

Another challenge could be that you're writing code that doesn't have much logic to it, you're just delegating to other libraries to do the downloading and RSS parsing. This makes it hard to squeeze the problem down. In that case, this could be a fairly uninteresting example to try to practice on. Consider trying to test drive something like [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) as an interesting, but simpler problem.

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Comment: Since feedparser takes care of almost everything in this case it might be hard due to the delegation of tasks to other libraries. I feel your answer resonates the most with me in this case so I'll mark your answer as the accepted one. I'll try another problem instead of this one.

Comment: That is my experience with learning TDD as well. I started with a test that tested the final wanted behaviour. Then realized that test would never pass before all the little helper classes and functions were in place. So, designing first, then doing TDD on each "module" seems to me to be the best way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at [`nose`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/testing.html) and [`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/).

`nose` is a good module for testing and it compliments `unittest` well and provides a CLI command to run tests and uses plugins to give you more information about your testing platform's results (code coverage etc.)

`mock` is the way we stub or mock methods or objects which is especially useful for things like HTTP requests or objects which interact with services outside the scope of your testing.

In your example I would do some patching on your feeder object and set the return value to some of your edge cases and test to make sure it handles the cases correctly with `self.assertTrue`, `self.assertIsInstance` (inherited from `unittest.TestCase`) etc...

Typically when doing TDD in python while using `nose` and `unittest` I first write the skeleton of the TestCase with a `setUp` and sometimes a `tearDown` which will handle common mocking and stubs.  For each test method I define I first mock what I have to, set up the environment around the unittest then call the method/object and make assertions.

In traditional TDD you design the test first then build your code to make your test green.  Red->Green.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have 'and' in your test title you are testing two things. It's much better to test one thing at a time, so I suggest you should refactor your test into two.

Secondly you want to proceed in really really small steps. Think of the smallest possible thing you could do next, that's not going to work with the current codebase.

When you have no code generally the smallest possible thing is to create an example of your target class. Don't ask it to do anything, just create it.

Which is pretty much the situation you are in. So you are doing it right!

Your code should not compile, because there is no TvSchedule. 'Not compiling' counts as Red. Write some code to make it compile, that's Green. Yay!

As noted by others, you should keep a little TODO list somewhere. In Kent Beck's book he uses sticky notes. I like to have the TODO list in the test code file. The scope of your todo list should be what you intend to accomplish in the time you are going to spend eg half an hour or two hours or whatever. Not the whole day, just from now until your next break. Then you add and substract things from your TODO list as you go. Helps keep you focused on doing 'the simplest thing that could possibly go wrong' to do next.

[EDIT: added TODO list]